# How to make a web2py site a trusted site

Tags: https, web2py, pythonanywhere, godaddy-api, trusted-sites

So I have this website that I made in web2py and launched using python anywhere. I am using godaddy to host the domain.

When I go to the website though it is not https and is not trusted. So, I bought the trusted site trustmark from godaddy and they are telling me to add a line of javascript into the code of the website to make it trusted.

But, I can't figure out where to put this line of code. What file do I put this code in in web2py to make the entire site https?

Answer (score 1):

Add the specified `<script>` tag near the bottom of the `/views/layout.html` file of the web2py app, which will result in it being included in every page that extends that layout (if you serve some pages with a different layout or without extending a layout, then you'll need to separately include the code in those views as well).